# Como hacer un conteo de fechas cada 15 dias

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe de 3825 filas y 42 columnas de las cuales expondré aquí un ejemplo con las dos filas que me hacen falta:

```
           Ingreso        Sexo
         2019-10-20       M
         2014-11-20       F
         2015-04-21       M
         2019-10-20       M
         2014-11-21       M
         2014-11-20       F
         2014-11-21       M
         2014-11-21       M
         2014-11-21       M
         2014-11-20       F
```

Quiero realizar un histograma por fechas, pero para ello antes tengo que realizar un conteo para 15 dias.

El siguiente código lo tomé de otra página el cual muestra como realizarlo por meses. Sin embargo yo lo necesito por cada 15 dias

```
     aggregate(
        count ~ wkday ,
        data=transform(BD,
                         wkday=format(as.Date(Ingreso), "%Y/%m"),
                         count=1),
          FUN=sum
        )
```

¿Qué debo modificar para que lo tome cada 15 días y que además me diference el conteo para hombres (M) y mujeres (F)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la "quincena" se calcula como días corridos desde la primer fecha de la base de datos, puedes calcular cual le corresponde a cada fecha, tomando la diferencia en días desde la primer fecha dividiendo esta por 15:

```
BD$quincena <- as.integer(floor((BD$Ingreso - min(BD$Ingreso)) / 15) + 1)
aggregate(. ~ Sexo + quincena, BD, length)

  Sexo quincena Ingreso
1    F        1       3
2    M        1       4
3    M       11       1
4    M      120       2
```

También puedes definir la quincena en función del día del mes y modificar, si el día es superior a 15 es la segunda y si es menor es la primera, y en función de esto establecer una fecha "falsa", por ejemplo el día 01 para la primer quincena, el 16 para la segunda:

```
BD$quincena <- as.Date(paste0(format(BD$Ingreso, "%Y-%m-"), ifelse(as.integer(format(BD$Ingreso, "%d")) > 15, "16", "01")))
aggregate(. ~ Sexo + quincena, BD, length)


  Sexo   quincena Ingreso
1    F 2014-11-16       3
2    M 2014-11-16       4
3    M 2015-04-16       1
4    M 2019-10-16       2
```

Estas soluciones parten de los datos actuales, si eventualmente faltaran fechas, obviamente faltarán "quincenas", en algún que otro análisis esto puede ser un problema, en cuyo caso tal vez te sea más útil trabajar directamente con series de tiempo.

Comment: Gracias Patricio por tu pronta respuesta. El código se ejecuta correctamente pero no me realice un conteo exacto, infravalora el conteo real y además etiqueta todas los conteos de un mes en la misma quincena (2020-03-16,  2020-04-16, en adelante). ¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?

Comment: Hola Adrián, es un error typografico, quise modificar algo y lo hice en el lugar incorrecto, el código sería `BD$quincena <- as.Date(paste0(format(BD$Ingreso, "%Y-%m-"), ifelse(as.integer(format(BD$Ingreso, "%d")) > 15, "16", "01")))`, pruebalo y cualquier cosa me dices.

Comment: Hola Patricio, con esta última modificación se soluciona el problema de que solo registre una quince. Sin embargo sigue sin hacer un conteo proporcional al número de casos que hay en cada quincena. Perdona las molestias

Comment: Es parte se me escapó, a que te refieres con proporcional? a los conteos diarios de cada quincena?

Comment: Si, por ejemplo para la fecha 2021-06-01 hay un registro de 7 hombres y 6 mujeres. Sin embargo tras aplicar el aggregate me sustituye el valor de todas las columnas por 2 y 1 que no se corresponde con los valores registro. Para otras fechas como 2021-05-01 es 3 y 3

Comment: De todas maneras esto último ya lo he solucionado con un group_by:  cuantos_tipos<-group_by(BD,Sexo,quincena)%>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
  );cuantos_tipos;dim(cuantos_tipos) Muchas gracias Patricio